# Django icontains query in manytomany relationship retrieves duplicated rows

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this problem. I have 2 objects in the model of my Django application, i have Tags, and i have Questions that contains more than one Tag, its a manytomany relationship. I’m trying to create a query with a Q object that is something like this:

```
questions = questions.filter(Q(title__icontains=searchwords)
                             |Q(tags__name__icontains=searchwords))
```

The results of this query, potentially can bring me duplicated rows and its logic, because, the second condition is applied for every Tag in the Question, so for example if i have a Question with 3 tags "Pepe", "Pepi" and "Jose", and the searchwords are "pe", then the query it will matches with "Pepe" and "Pepi", and finally its going to bring back 2 rows corresponding to the same Question.

So my question is, how do i avoid the duplicated rows? (don’t want to use distinct()), there’s something in Django like icontains but only matches with the first Tag coincidence.

Well i tried my best in the explanation, sorry my bad English. Greeteings.

Comment: What if you reverse the query, using .exclude() and ~Q()

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `distinct()` and if you are not using PostgreSQL you'll need to use `order_by()`, too.

```
questions = questions.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=searchwords)|Q(tags__name__icontains=searchwords)
).order_by('some_field').distinct()
```

Comment: Hi, I already have the distinct, but i'm trying to improve the performance of this query because its the main search of the application, and its a bit slow. Thanks for the advice, i'm going to see if i can order by some field to optimize.